# Prevent "float:right" div from occupying the entire space

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float, bootstrap-5

I was working a reddit clone and stumbled on a problem.

**FYI: Using bootstrap v5.0**

The problem is that I want the side bar to the right and the content to the left but here it works all fine but the content section occupies the space left for the side bar and pushes the side bar down.

[image]

Here is the code

```
<div>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 80px;">
        <div class="posts jumbotron">
            <div class="post">
                <h3 class="post-heading"><a href="#">Lorem</a></h3>
                <p class="post-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus maxime odio soluta eveniet, illum rem corporis minima velit quam voluptatibus earum quae quibusdam aut molestias? Consequuntur quibusdam odio culpa delectus!</p>
                <hr style="height: 3px; margin-top: 30px;">
                <br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <h3 class="post-heading"><a href="#">Lorem</a></h3>
                <p class="post-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus maxime odio soluta eveniet, illum rem corporis minima velit quam voluptatibus earum quae quibusdam aut molestias? Consequuntur quibusdam odio culpa delectus!</p>
                <hr style="height: 3px; margin-top: 30px;">
                <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar jumbotron">
        <h3 class="brand">Joined subfredits</h3>

        <br><br>

        <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Some text</a><p>
        <hr>
        <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Some text</a><p>
        <hr>
        <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Some text</a><p>
        <hr>

    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    padding: 50px;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 50px 100px -20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 30px 60px -30px, rgba(10, 37, 64, 0.35) 0px -2px 6px 0px inset;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    width: 20%;
}

.posts {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: don't use float right, you can use the BS5 class or directly flexbox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a float left:

```
.posts {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 50px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: @tacoshy but it works all fine for me whats the problem?

Comment: because it is bad practise and not usefull for programmers that dont want to make rookie mistakes and programm in a correct, clean an modern way.

Comment: The problem is that float remove your content from normal flow. And in the 2021 isnt the correct approach. I'll suggest you to learn how BS5 grid works (you can read the docs) to obtain your desired layout

Answer (score 0):

The correct ways to achieve this with **Bootstrap** include the following methods:

- Using the [BS grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/) with the proper structure `.container`>`.row`>`.col`:

```css
/* the selectors have higher sepecifity to override BS rules */

.sidebar.jumbotron {
  /* float: right; */
  padding: 50px;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 50px 100px -20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 30px 60px -30px, rgba(10, 37, 64, 0.35) 0px -2px 6px 0px inset;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* margin-right: 150px; */
  /* width: 20%; */
}

.posts.jumbotron {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  /* width: 75%;*/
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 80px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="posts jumbotron col-8">
      <div class="post">
        <h3 class="post-heading"><a href="#">Lorem</a></h3>
        <p class="post-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus maxime odio soluta eveniet, illum rem corporis minima velit quam voluptatibus earum quae quibusdam aut molestias? Consequuntur quibusdam odio culpa delectus!</p>
        <hr style="height: 3px; margin-top: 30px;">
        <br><br>
      </div>
      <div class="post">
        <h3 class="post-heading"><a href="#">Lorem</a></h3>
        <p class="post-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus maxime odio soluta eveniet, illum rem corporis minima velit quam voluptatibus earum quae quibusdam aut molestias? Consequuntur quibusdam odio culpa delectus!</p>
        <hr style="height: 3px; margin-top: 30px;">
        <br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar jumbotron col-4">
      <h3 class="brand">Joined subfredits</h3>

      <br><br>

      <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Some text</a>
      </p>
      <hr>
      <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Some text</a>
      </p>
      <hr>
      <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Some text</a>
      </p>
      <hr>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

- Using BS [flex utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/) `.d-flex` & `.flex-row`

```css
.sidebar.jumbotron {
  /* float: right; */
  padding: 50px;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 50px 100px -20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 30px 60px -30px, rgba(10, 37, 64, 0.35) 0px -2px 6px 0px inset;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* margin-right: 150px; */
  /* width: 20%; */
}

.posts.jumbotron {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  /* width: 75%;*/
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 80px;">

  <!-- This -->
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">

    <div class="posts jumbotron">
      <div class="post">
        <h3 class="post-heading"><a href="#">Lorem</a></h3>
        <p class="post-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus maxime odio soluta eveniet, illum rem corporis minima velit quam voluptatibus earum quae quibusdam aut molestias? Consequuntur quibusdam odio culpa delectus!</p>
        <hr style="height: 3px; margin-top: 30px;">
        <br><br>
      </div>
      <div class="post">
        <h3 class="post-heading"><a href="#">Lorem</a></h3>
        <p class="post-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus maxime odio soluta eveniet, illum rem corporis minima velit quam voluptatibus earum quae quibusdam aut molestias? Consequuntur quibusdam odio culpa delectus!</p>
        <hr style="height: 3px; margin-top: 30px;">
        <br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar jumbotron">
      <h3 class="brand">Joined subfredits</h3>

      <br><br>

      <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Some text</a>
      </p>
      <hr>
      <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Some text</a>
      </p>
      <hr>
      <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link">Some text</a>
      </p>
      <hr>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```